# Convert Binary string to Hex string without losing leading zeros

Tags: c#, string, binary, hex

I am trying to convert Binary string to hex, however I miss the zero values, I mean Binary string 000001010100 should become hex string 054?

I'm currently using

```
Convert.ToInt32(value,2).ToString("X")
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're currently using to do the conversion?

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(value,2).ToString("X")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use

```
Convert.ToInt32(value,2).ToString("X3")
```

where the number following the X is the minimum number of digits you want in the final string. I used the number 3, because that was the output you included as an example. It's explained in more detail in this [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: +1. fine for small numbers. Consider `"x"+(value.Length / 4)` as format if need to handle 1-4 hex digits.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string in four digit parts, parse them and format into a hex digit. That gives you the correct number of digits. Example:

```
string bin = "000001010100";
string hex = String.Concat(
  Regex.Matches(bin, "....").Cast<Match>()
  .Select(m => Convert.ToInt32(m.Value, 2)
  .ToString("x1"))
);
```

Comment: +1. Handles arbitrary length of strings as long it is aligned to 4 bits. If need to also handle non-aligned strings consider `for` loop and cut out sub-strings instead of `Regex`.